# Using Natural Deduction to Prove $(P \land Q) \to R \vdash (P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently using a sequent calculus and natural deduction to prove this derivation. The book I'm using ("Logic" by Tomassi) claims that this can be completed using only 24 lines. Here is what I have so far:

[image: Proof]

So far I'm stuck as to how to get $(P \land Q)$ so I can use RAA in the space between lines 12-16. I'm not sure if this is the correct path to take but it's the closest I've gotten to solving this problem so far. There are other answers here, but they either contain rules of inference not mentioned in the book so far (DeMorgan's Law, Law of Excluded Middle, Principle of Explosion, etc) or are far beyond 24 lines. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your current approach, you are trying to derive $(P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$ by contradiction assuming its negation, and as an intermediate goal deriving $(P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$ from $P \to R$. Two comments on that:

Comment: 1. If your intermediate goal is to derive $(P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$ anyway, then assuming its negation and doing double negation is elimination to arrive at the unnegated statement is redundant -- since you will already have shown $(P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$ directly. Indirect proofs with assuming the negation of the formula are only useful when the formula can not be shown directly without further assumptions, but this seems to be what you are intending to do on line 21.

Comment: 2. You are apparently trying to show $(P \to R) \lor (Q \to R)$ by $\lor I$ on $P \to R$. However, this requires showing $P \to R$, and this is not possible from the assumptions you have. Instead of a $\lor I$ on one of the disjuncts, you need to prove the disjunction indirectly by assuming its negation and deriving a contradiction from some additional assumptions.

Comment: Can you give a list of which rules *have* been mentioned up to this point so we can get an idea of exactly what restrictions you're under?

Comment: @lemontree Your comment #1 isn't necessarily correct, if the extra hypothesis of $\lnot((P\rightarrow R)\vee (Q\rightarrow R))$ is useful in deducing $(P\rightarrow R)\vee (Q\rightarrow R)$.  (See for example the standard proof of $P \vee \lnot P$ by double negation elimination, which has an intermediate goal of $\lnot P$ *assuming* $\lnot(P \vee \lnot P)$.)

Comment: My suggestion, without these restrictions would be: if you assume both $(P\wedge Q \rightarrow R)$ and $\lnot((P\rightarrow R) \vee (Q\rightarrow R))$, then with an extra hypothesis of $P$ you can prove $Q\rightarrow R$, giving a contradiction, so by explosion you can conclude $R$; therefore, $P \rightarrow R$, again giving a contradiction.  But since you mentioned not having principle of explosion...

Comment: So, for example, say your problem was to show $\lnot P \vdash (P \rightarrow R)$.  How would you prove that with the rules you have so far?

Comment: @Daniel Schepler so far the rules are: &Intro, &Elim, vIntro, vElim, Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Conditional Proof, Biconditional Intro, Biconditional Elim, Double Negation Intro, Double Negation Elim, and Reductio Ad Absurdum

Comment: @Daniel Schepler Hence my addition *without further assumptions*. In the standard proof of $p \lor \neg p$, the two subderivations of $p \lor \neg p$ to derive a contradiction twice to $\neg (p \lor \neg p)$ depend on an additional assumptions that are only later discharged, so $p \lor \neg p$ can not be proven directly. The same applies to the formula to be proved in this question: Line 21 must depend on more than/be nested deeper than the assumption of its negation, it can not be proven directly without further assumptions.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I would show $\neg P \vdash (P \to R)$ by assuming $P$, then assuming $\neg Q$, then giving a contradiction giving me $Q$, then by conditional proof getting $P \to Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof from https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ with the restrictions you mentioned in comments.

(Note that in lines 5 through 10, the assumption of $\lnot R$ is never used.  Therefore, if you were allowed to use the principle of explosion, I would remove lines 4 and 11, and simply justify line 12 from line 10 using this principle.  I also tend to use the "IP" rule from the linked site instead of a combination of ${\rightarrow}I$ and DNE, which would allow dropping line 16.)

[image: proof screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. I was able to construct a 34 line proof using the hints you gave but you were able to construct a proof in a much more elegant style. Is there a strategy that you use to determine what type of proof you should do?

Comment: Aside: whenever I do these proofs (especially when they require classical reasoning), I like to think of what the corresponding function under the Curry-Howard correspondence does.  In this case, the function is "first guess $P\rightarrow R$ is true, with proof being a synthetic function.  If that function is ever called, use the input proof of $P$ to construct a proof of $Q\rightarrow R$, rewind execution, and return that as the proof of $(P\rightarrow R)\vee(Q\rightarrow R)$ instead."

Comment: @Cizox I don't know that I can really outline a specific strategy, it's just that I have a lot of practice using the Coq proof assistant for formalized proofs which operates on similar principles to this system.  (That said, there *is* a mechanized procedure for solving intuitionistic propositional logic problems, and if that fails, then after a single application of DNE at the root of the proof, the procedure will work if the originally sequent is true for classical logic.  That search procedure would end up coming up with something very like this.)

Answer (score 1):

**Long story short:** Don't take the long round about.

You have assumed $\neg(p\to r)$ in you third line with the aim of deriving a contradiction so that you can discharge that assumption to deduce $p\to r$ so that you can derive a contradiction ... That is a bit of a scenic detour.

Should the conditional statement $p\to r$ be derivable, then a conditional proof will be possible. Just do that thing.

> Is there a strategy that you use to determine what type of proof you should do? – Cizox

Yes.   When you seek to prove a disjunction from a premise you will *either* be introducing a disjunction after proving at least one from the two disjuncts directly, *or* you will be using an indirect proof (proof by contradiction).

Here neither $(p\to r)$ nor $(q\to r)$ seems to be directly implied by $(p\wedge q)\to r$.   If you assume $p$ you cannot immediately infer $r$ from the premise.

This indicates the non-intuitivist route should be attempted: Aim to prove that the consequent cannot be false. $\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

$$\fitch{(p\wedge q)\to r}{\fitch{\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\neg\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)}$$

Now to do that we try to do what could not be done directly: prove at least one of the disjuncts can be derived *under the assumption*.   Either should be derivable if the assumption is indeed contradictable, so try the first.

$p\to r$ is a conditional statement, so a Conditional Proof is indicated. Assume $p$ aiming to derive $r$ so that the conditional may be introduced.

$$\fitch{(p\wedge q)\to r}{\fitch{\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))}{\fitch{p}{~\vdots\\ r}\\p\to r\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)\\\bot}\\\neg\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)}$$

But how to derive $r$ from those assumptions?   Well, again we might be able to prove by contradiction that $r$ cannot be false.

So now, we are aiming for a another contradiction, so perhaps we should try to derive the other disjunct, $q\to r$?

Indeed; since we have already assumed $p$, we can do that.

$$\fitch{(p\wedge q)\to r}{\fitch{\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))}{\fitch{p}{\fitch{\neg r}{\fitch{q}{p\wedge q\\r}\\q\to r\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)\\\bot}\\\neg\neg r\\ r}\\p\to r\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)\\\bot}\\\neg\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)}$$

Proof done, mostly.   Just add line numbers and justifications for each inference.

---

On further inspection, (as @DanielSchepler notes) as $\neg r$ is never invoked in the subproof, $r$ can be derived using the principle of explosion, *if* that is considered a fundamental rule of inference in your ND system.

$$\fitch{(p\wedge q)\to r}{\fitch{\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))}{\fitch{p}{\fitch{q}{p\wedge q\\r}\\q\to r\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)\\\bot\\ r}\\p\to r\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)\\\bot}\\\neg\neg((p\to r)\vee(q\to r))\\(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)}$$